# Place items one line using android constraint layout 2.0.0 Flow

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I tried to use new android Flow layout. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/helper/Flow. I have this screen, items in flow layout and expander (now is open). When expander is closed i want to place only first line (4 items).

[image]

My xml flow layout

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
                    android:id="@+id/fr_mail_viewer_attachments_flow"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
                    app:flow_horizontalGap="8dp"
                    app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
                    app:flow_verticalBias="0"
                    app:flow_verticalGap="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/fr_mail_viewer_attachments_expander"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I tried to use `app:flow_maxElementsWrap="1"` and it didn't help me

[image]

Can anyone help me or share some resourses about flow layout?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you want to wrap after 4 elements as I see in your picture. You should add app:flow_maxElementsWrap="4" to your Flow widget. Also, keep in mind that you can set the orientation to the flow widget to control how items in a chain are laid out:

```
                <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
                    android:id="@+id/fr_mail_viewer_attachments_flow"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
                    app:flow_horizontalGap="8dp"
                    app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
                    app:flow_verticalBias="0"
                    app:flow_verticalGap="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
                    app:flow_maxElementsWrap="4"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/fr_mail_viewer_attachments_expander"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```